# Calculate column rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How do I calculate the column rank of the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -4 & -6 & 0 \\ 0 & -12 & 24 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 28 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

I initially thought it would be $3$ as there are $3$ pivots. But then I realized that it will give me the row rank. Is that correct? If yes, then how do I calculate the column rank using pivots or otherwise?

Comment: This depends on your field. Over the field $\Bbb F_2$ this is the zero matrix. Over a field of characteristic zero, the rank is obviously $3$, because column rank equals the row rank - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383265/intuitive-proof-of-row-rank-column-rank) for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was considering $\mathbb{R}$ as the field.